# Why countries like to create their own cryptocurrency?

Tags: currencies

Why countries like to create their own cryptocurrency?  As far as I know, a good cryptocurrency should have independent of a third party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just thinking now the possibility of government issued crypto currency (maybe blockchain technology) and the miners are the banks only, this way government is not putting banks out of business and there can still be central bank who controls all the banks and issue order if needed more money in the economy (if Etherium based which I think the preferred type of all governments).

This can even go in parallel with government existing fiats so people can have two choices (good publicity for the government).

But the question still remains the same, if ever government wants to push on this, "how can they know who owns what?" If this can be solved I think government will definitely step into the world of crypto currencies....